# Rails - Parsing nested form association errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to display association errors using an index key object with the following format:

```
:errors=>{
  :questions=>{
     0=>{:title=>"can't be blank"},
     1=>{:title=>"can't be blank"}
  }
}
```

Rails 5 provides a way to display error indexes but using a format like:

```
questions[0].title, 
questions[1].title
```

My solution which is a bit nasty, is parsing the error response like this

```
def parse_errors
  {
    errors: {
      questions: @post.questions.enum_for(:each_with_index).collect { |question, index|
        {
           index => question.errors.messages
        } unless question.valid?
      }.inject({}, :merge).transform_values {|v| v.transform_values &:first }
   }.merge!(@post.errors.messages)
  }
 end
```

I get

```
{
  :errors=>{
    :questions=>{
      0=>{
        :title=>"can't be blank"
      },
      1=>{
        :title=>"can't be blank"
      }
    }, 
    :"questions.title"=>["can't be blank"], 
    :title=>["can't be blank"]
  }
}
```

But i expect the following result omitting the default question error message :"questions.title"=>["can't be blank"],
Like this:

```
{
  :errors=>{
    :questions=>{
      0=>{
        :title=>"can't be blank"
      },
      1=>{
        :title=>"can't be blank"
      }
    },  
    :title=>["can't be blank"]
  }
}
```

So, is there any way to clean up this code in order to show errors for post and questions with the expected format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Parsing nested form association errors

Not Sure, but You can remove default error messages by:

1. Clear all the errors with `self.errors.clear`.
2. Put all the error messages back in the right/desired places using `self.errors.add`.

Comment: @Andrés Da Viá if you satisfied with my answer then make it correct and vote up.